# Getting all records from a relation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following Laravel model:

```
class User extends ConfideUser implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    use HasRole;

    public function stores()
    {
        if ($this->hasRole('root')) {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Store')->orWhereNull('store_user.user_id');
        } else {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Store');
        }
    }
}
```

Each `user` belongs to many `store`s and this relation is created through the standard pivot table `'store_user'`.

If I do the following, I get all the stores for a user:

```
$stores = Auth::user()->stores;
```

However, if that user has the `root` role, I want to retrieve all of the stores. This would be simple enough to return all stores using a simple select, but for the `stores()` method to functional consistently, Laravel expects it to return object of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`.

How can I return a `Relation` object with all of the stores selected instead of just the ones that the root user has in the `store_user` pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

not good at models BUT....... this may work

```
    public function stores()
{
    if ($this->hasRole('root')) {
        $all_stores = DB::table('where_ever_stores_are')->get();
        return $all_stores;
    } else {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Store');
    }
}
```

This will only return all the stores, as for the relation that may be harder, what is the out put you are wanting in the returned Array??

Comment: I don't think this will return a Relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design of having that check is plain wrong!

simply have

```
public function stores()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Store');
}
```

And have your Controller do the check:

```
public function inMyController()
{
    if ( $user->hasRole('root') ) {
        return Store::all();
    } else {
        return $user->stores;
    }
}
```

Your Model should only bother about the model itself instead of taking care of the permissions.

Better approach would be to have a Repository that handles all the queriying of the models. And you controller then simply talks to the repository.

Comment: The `User` model has permission and role management directly through the `Confide` and `Entrust` class packages. I'm just trying to extend the functionality from the `User` model because that relation is also accessible through `Auth` and via eager loading, which is very convenient in the rest of the code. If I move it to the controller, I lose that and have to go the IoC route to access those features through other models and controllers.